# Prevent viewing of robots.txt file for asp.net websites

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ihttpmodule

If someone type http://somewebsite.com/robots.txt they'll be able to view the content of the file. This would give hackers a leg up.

I did a little research and found that there's a solution for this for Apache. Has anyone ever seen this for asp.net application?

Comment: The "trick" is to check if the browser is one of the spider bots, but this is also can be very easy hacked - so is pointless to try to hide that file, is better to not give there any information that they can not be found anyway.

Comment: Thanks Aristos, I just won't provide any directories that google would never find on its own.